# MantisBT log-in gives error 500 for non-Administrator accounts

Tags: php, mantis

I've set up MantisBT on a server and have created a few dummy projects so that I can get-to-grips with it. It works fine for the administrator account and all others which are given administrator privileges.

I created an account (reporter) with reporter status and attempted to log-in. The body of the page I receive is:

```
<body>
<div id="mantis">
<div id="banner"><a id="logo-link" href="my_view_page.php"><img id="logo-image" alt="MantisBT" src="/mantisbt/images/mantis_logo.png" /></a></div><div id="login-info"><span id="logged-in-label">Logged in as</span><span id="logged-in-user">reporter</span><span id="logged-in"><span id="logged-in-accesslevel" class="reporter">reporter</span></span></div><div id="rss-feed"><a href="http://192.168.1.59/mantisbt/issues_rss.php?username=reporter&amp;key=ly2yP65wsoKZcf2Row8Kf2drCSmxlaCAAqxOhXYw5IDQq_gYjq9l5hwLUcsXcD7QcYCmQfbGXrF3P8D5V5G_"><img src="/mantisbt/images/rss.png" alt="RSS" title="RSS" /></a></div><div id="project-selector"><form method="post" id="form-set-project" action="/mantisbt/set_project.php"><fieldset id="project-selector"><label for="form-set-project-id">Project</label><select id="form-set-project-id" name="project_id"><option value="0" selected="selected">All Projects</option>
<option value="5">Bug Tracking</option>
Input Array does not match ?: SELECT DISTINCT p.id, p.name, ph.parent_id
                      FROM mantis_project_table p
                      LEFT JOIN mantis_project_user_list_table u
                        ON p.id = u.project_id AND u.user_id=9
                      LEFT JOIN mantis_project_hierarchy_table ph
                        ON ph.child_id = p.id
                      WHERE p.enabled = 10 AND 
                        ph.parent_id IS NOT NULL AND
                        ( p.view_state=50
                            OR (p.view_state=9
                                AND
                                u.user_id=<br>
```

One reason this surprises me is that MantisBT presents the project enabled status as a checkbox, which updates `mantis_project_table.enabled` between `1` and `0` but this wants a value of `10`

I've pinned this down to the function `user_get_accessible_subprojects` in file `mantisbt/core/user_api.php:1021`. The query that should have executed is:

```
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT p.id, p.name, ph.parent_id
          FROM $t_project_table p
          LEFT JOIN $t_project_user_list_table u
            ON p.id = u.project_id AND u.user_id=" . db_param() . "
          LEFT JOIN $t_project_hierarchy_table ph
            ON ph.child_id = p.id
          WHERE " . ($p_show_disabled ? '' : ('p_enabled = ' . db_param() . ' AND ')) . ' 
            ph.parent_id IS NOT NULL AND
            ( p.view_state=' . db_param() . '
                OR (p.view_state=' . db_param() . '
                AND
                    u.user_id=' . db_param() . ' )
)
ORDER BY p.name';
```

I don't intend to modify the source code since I expect I've made an obvious mistake, but hope that it may help those that are less familiar with MantisBT identify the issue.

I can provide further information about the database contents (Users, Projects etc.) if need be

Comment: What version of MantisBT do you use and what database engine?